Localstack -- Unable to store binary secret using Secrets Manager?
I'm trying to store a PKCS#12 file in Localstack's SecretsManager.  I have the following terraform code to do so:
data "local_file" "keystore" {
    filename = "${path.module}/my_certificate.p12"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "keystore" {
    provider = aws.localstack
    name = "test"

    recovery_window_in_days = 0
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "keystore" {
    provider = aws.localstack
    secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.keystore.id
    secret_binary = data.local_file.keystore.content_base64
}

The terraform apply completes successfully, but when I retrieve it with this command...
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 --secret-id test --version-stage AWSCURRENT --query 'SecretBinary' --output text | base64 --decode > testout.p12

...I only get a 230 byte value that is not my PKCS#12 file.  At first I thought it was an issue with my terraform code, but I changed it to use the actual AWS provider instead of localstack and it worked fine.  When I get the secret value it matches the PKCS#12 file I was expecting.
Does Localstack not support binary secrets?  I didn't see any documentation that indicated this was a limitation.  Am I doing something wrong here?

I would not be surprised to learn that localstack didn't completely implement this.  especially if you're not paying them.  They're trying their best to kneecap the free offering to push folks into the paid subscription.  There are also implementation gaps in  moto3 which underlies most if not all of localstack iirc.
